What are better substitutes for "The synopsis of pure mathematics"?
As many of you might already know, The book "Synopsis of pure mathematics" by G.S. Carr is a classic book, covering most of the mathematics known at its time. The book's structure is mainly just mentioning theorems and their applications without being burdened by proofs or exercises. However due to its age, its fairly archaic ways and it not being available physically, this book is far from an ideal book to study subjects in pure mathematics. What are some textbooks with similar structure to this one that are more up to date. That is, what are some of the mathematics textbooks, which attempt to summarize subjects of pure mathematics up to grad level, and don't pay much attention to proofs or exercises and thus have a more encyclopedia-esque structure. The best example that I myself found, though not a book, is the website Wolfram MathWorld.
Bottom line, what are some up to date, encyclopediae of math, covering up to the highest possible level.

I’ve heard of a Princeton Companion that was apparently pretty good, but I can’t recall any specifics at all, so treat this with extreme caution.

it not being available physically --- It is available in many libraries, in fact 12 libraries within 300 miles of where I live (according to this), including a public library (Kansas City Public Library). There are also probably original hardcopies for sale, but my guess is in more recent years (last 20 years) these are harder to find at a reasonable price due to its large number of mentions on the internet, similar to how copies of Advanced Calculus by Woods (book Feynman studied) are astronomical compared to similar (era and topic) such books.

"Princeton Companion" is an excellent book. In a very different perspective, a delightful book in 4 volumes, full of anecdotes, that you can find on some old shelves "The World of Mathematics" By James R. Newman.

You might be interested in the Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mathematics. It is a Japanese work. It's third edition was translated into English in 1993. As far as I know, the most recent edition (the fourth one) has never been translated.

More details can be found here, but I wouldn't classify this as something "up to grad level"; maybe "up through grad level". It's also not a "mathematics textbook", but my guess is the OP is not actually looking for a "textbook". (Maybe the OP also meant "up through grad level" $\ldots)$
